# Geometry question about transversals

Tags: geometry

[I’m seriously stuck on this question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnxDE.png)I know that I’ll have to use something like the converse alternate interior angles theorem, or the converse corresponding angles theorem, but I’m not sure how to get to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\overline{SA}\cong \overline{SI}$ and $T$ bisects $\overline{AI}$ will tell us that $\angle STI=\angle STR=90^\circ$ since we have a side, side, side triangle congruence.

$\overline{PA}\cong \overline{PT}$ and $R$ bisects $\overline{AT}$ will similarly tell us that $\angle ARE=\angle ERT=90^\circ$.

Now, since $\angle ERT=\angle STR=90^\circ$, we can conclude $\overline{EP}\parallel\overline{ST}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! My upvote won't display since my "reputation" isn't high enough.

Comment: @tk21 No problem!